# How to multiply two FFTs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft, zero-padding

I want to find the output signal(y) from input signal(x) and impulse response(h). To do that first I take the fft of both x and h, then multiply them, and finally taking the ifft of the result. The input signal is a 5 second sound. I tried to equalize the lengths of the FFTs but it didnt work. How can I overcome this?

```
[x,Fs]=audioread('hello.wav');

T=1/Fs;

L=220500;%length of the original sound

d=8820;%delay in terms of samples

a=0.8;%attenuation coefficient

h = [1 zeros(1,d-1) a];%impulse response h(n)

X=fft(x);

h1 =[h; zeros(length(x)-length(h),1)];

H=fft(h1);

Y=H.*X;

y=ifft(Y);
```

Comment: why do you use the `;` for `h1` but not for `h`?  are you converting from a column vector to a row vector?  maybe my MATLAB skills are rusty,

Comment: For a very long input signal and a relatively shorter impulse response, it's inefficient to calculate their convolution with one FFT. A better idea is to separate the long signal into several pieces and use overlap-add or overlap-save. And as Fat32 pointed, the length of circular convolution (multiplication in frequency domain) should be at least $N+L-1$ point so that the result is identical with the linear convolution.

Answer (score 1):

You have two signals of length $N = 220500$ and $ L =  8821$ samples long, and you want to obtain their convolution $y[n]$ of length $K = N + L-1 = 229320$ samples long, by using a frequency-domain DFT//FFT method...

Then you have to compute $K = N + L -1 = 229320$ sample long FFTs of both signals $x[n]$ and $h[n]$, and then multiply them, and then invert the resulting spectrum back into time-domain as given by the following MATLAB line.

```
% assuming x[n] and h[n] exist....
N = 220500;  % length of x[n]
L = 8821;    % length of impulse response h[n]
K = N+ K -1; % length of output y[n] = x[n] * h[n]

y = real( ifft( fft(x,K).*fft(h,K) , K ); % y[n]:
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

1. Multiplying FFTs implements circular convolution, not linear convolution. In order to get the correct result of the filtering operation proper zero padding is required. Read up on "overlap add" convolution.
2. If the length of the signal and the filter are very different, it's inefficient to do an FFT over the whole thing. Instead break up the signal into "blocks". Again, "overlap add" handles this well.
3. If you really just want to apply a delay, that's much easier done directly in the time domain.